# Cannot remove commas from input type number value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, validation, input

I'm trying to remove the commas from an input value using JS / jQuery.

The input type is number and I'm running the sanitisation process on key up.

The below code works fine when the input type is text, but not when the input type is number.

I'm using the input type number as a currency input, hence why I'm attempting to remove commas incase someone inputs $1,000 for example.

And I'd like to use input type number as this will mainly be used on mobile devices.

Does anyone know why that might be please?

-

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/YXvxxK

```js
$('.form input').on('keyup', function() {
  field1 = $('#field1').val();
  var newField1 = parseFloat(field1.replace(/,/g, ''));
  console.log(newField1);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="form">
  <input type="number" id="field1" />
</form>
```

Comment: Inout type number does not give you the value when it is invalid.

Comment: You can add `console.log(field1 );` when user  input `commas ` at wrong position,the value is empty

Comment: Just a side note since this has already been answered, but a number input doesn't actually make anything easier on a mobile device. On an iPhone the keyboard that shows is the exact same for type text and type number.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts that sounds device-specific or even mobile-browser-specific. Chrome on Android opens a numeric keypad if the `type` is `number`.

Comment: @JamesDonnelly then in that case OP would *want* to use type text to give the same UX to everyone. My observation is device-specific rather than browser-specific so the way I phrased it was correct since I specified.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The problem here isn't that you can't remove the commas, it's that commas aren't valid* within `input` elements whose `type` is `number`.

If we enter "1,234" into the field within your code snippet and hit <kbd>Return</kbd>, we're greeted with the following validation error:

[image: Example]

This happens because the value "1,234" is deemed invalid. As this is invalid, the element's `value` will return as an empty string instead of the string value "1,234".

`parseFloat("".replace(/,/g, ''))` returns `NaN`.

A quick *fix* to this is to stop using the `number` input type and use `text` instead. However that may not be what you desire. Another way would be to detect whether the `value` is empty (`""`) and present the user with a validation failure message.

---

* *It's important to note that this is implementation-specific. The HTML5 specification states that browser vendors are ["encouraged to consider what would best serve their users' needs"](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#number-state-(type=number)). Treating a comma here as invalid is part of that consideration.*